# Prisma не добавляет список в SqLite

Tags: node.js, json, express, node-modules, prisma

Схема призма:

```
model Countrie {
  id           Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  nameCountrie String
  Video        Video? @relation(fields: [videoId], references: [id])
  videoId      Int?
}

model Actor {
  id         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  posterUrl  String?
  name       String
  surname    String?
  patronymic String?
  Video      Video?  @relation(fields: [videoId], references: [id])
  videoId    Int? 
}

model Video {
  id             Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  title          String     @unique
  ratingFilm     Float
  postersUrl     String
  yearCreate     Int
  countries      Countrie[]
  gendre         String
  content        String
  ageRestriction Int
  description    String
  actors         Actor[]
  url            String
  published      Boolean    @default(true)
}
```

Контроллер express:

```
export const downloadVideo = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const {
    id,
    title,
    ratingFilm,
    postersUrl,
    yearCreate,
    countries,
    gendre,
    content,
    ageRestriction,
    description,
    actors,
    url,
  } = req.body;

  const isHaveVideo = await prisma.video.findUnique({
    where: {
      title,
    },
  });

  if (isHaveVideo) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Video already exists");
  }

  console.log(countries)

  const createVideoToDatabase = await prisma.video.create({
    data: {
      title: title,
      ratingFilm: ratingFilm,
      postersUrl: postersUrl,
      yearCreate: yearCreate,
      countries: countries,
      gendre: gendre,
      content: content,
      ageRestriction: ageRestriction,
      description: description,
      actors: actors,
      url: url
    },
  });

  res.status(201);
  res.json(createVideoToDatabase);
});
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Error: 
Invalid prisma.video.create() invocation:

{
  data: {
    title: 'Гей среди нас',
    ratingFilm: 9.7,
    postersUrl: '/films/Airbuss/1.png',
    yearCreate: 2019,
    countries: [
      'Василий',
      'Иван'
    ],
    ~~~~~~~~~~
    gendre: 'Хорор',
    content: 'Любовь самолет вертолет корабль',
    ageRestriction: 18,
    description: 'Король кокаина, террорист, один из известнейших и богатейших преступников… Да, речь идёт о Пабло Эскобаре! Кража надгробий, продажа сигарет и подделка лотерейных билетов переросли в угон дорогих авто, рэкет и убийства. Фильм «Эскобар» – история наркобарона, семьянина и политика.1982 год. Наркобарон Пабло Эскобар знакомится с Вирхинией Валехо – известной журналисткой. Девушка становится его биографом и любовницей. Из мемуаров женщины мы узнаём о жизни и стремлениях Эскобара: он появляется в большой политике и занимает место в Конгрессе Колумбии. Будучи в большой политике, он сохраняет верность своим старым методам, отработанным в преступном мире: угрозы, насилие и шантаж. Но с началом антикокаиновой кампании его карьера в этой сфере заканчивается.После громкого скандала со взрывом Бионга над Баготой и волны политического террора карьера бывшего босса идёт к закату; на Эскобара начинается настоящая охота властей. Спустя пару лет он всё же сдаётся и переезжает в специальную тюрьму… Где для него организованы коттедж, сады, джакузи и рабочее место – ведь он продолжает управлять своим бизнесом. Впрочем, Пабло сбежал и оттуда. Смотри фильм «Эскобар» и узнай обо всех перипетиях судьбы одного из самых знаменитых в мире криминальных авторитетов!Кинокартина, снятая при участии Болгарии, Испании и США, основана на мемуарах Вирхинии Вальехо – той самой журналистки, по сюжету ставшей биографом Эскобара. Цепляет не только сюжет, но и звёздный актёрский состав: Хавьер Бардем и Пенелопа Крус, Питер Сарсгаард и Жульет Рестрепо. Впрочем, каждому из них пришлось потратить немало сил на то, чтобы вжиться в роль: Хавьер Бардем, к примеру, сильно набрал вес для роли, а Пенелопа Крус посмотрела десятки видео со своей героиней и призналась, что это была одна из сложнейших ролей в её карьере.',
    actors: [
      'Василий',
      'Иван'
    ],
    ~~~~~~~~~~
    url: '/films/Airbuss/1.mp4'
  }
}

Argument countries: Got invalid value 
[
  'Василий',
  'Иван'
]
on prisma.createOneVideo. Provided List<String>, expected CountrieCreateNestedManyWithoutVideoInput:
type CountrieCreateNestedManyWithoutVideoInput {
  create?: CountrieCreateWithoutVideoInput | List<CountrieCreateWithoutVideoInput> | CountrieUncheckedCreateWithoutVideoInput | List<CountrieUncheckedCreateWithoutVideoInput>
  connectOrCreate?: CountrieCreateOrConnectWithoutVideoInput | List<CountrieCreateOrConnectWithoutVideoInput>
  connect?: CountrieWhereUniqueInput | List<CountrieWhereUniqueInput>
}
Argument actors: Got invalid value 
[
  'Василий',
  'Иван'
]
on prisma.createOneVideo. Provided List<String>, expected ActorCreateNestedManyWithoutVideoInput:
type ActorCreateNestedManyWithoutVideoInput {
  create?: ActorCreateWithoutVideoInput | List<ActorCreateWithoutVideoInput> | ActorUncheckedCreateWithoutVideoInput | List<ActorUncheckedCreateWithoutVideoInput>
  connectOrCreate?: ActorCreateOrConnectWithoutVideoInput | List<ActorCreateOrConnectWithoutVideoInput>
  connect?: ActorWhereUniqueInput | List<ActorWhereUniqueInput>
}


    at Ui.validate (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New\smotriTyt\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:148:73)
    at gn.createMessage (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New\smotriTyt\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:164:1298)
    at C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New\smotriTyt\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:177:11600
    at Object.runInChildSpan (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New\smotriTyt\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:174:1394)
    at t._executeRequest (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New\smotriTyt\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:177:11577)
    at async file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/New/smotriTyt/server/video/video.controller.js:33:33
```

JSON из инсомнии:

```
{
  "title": "Гей среди нас",
  "ratingFilm": 9.7,
  "postersUrl": "/films/Airbuss/1.png",
  "yearCreate": 2019,
  "countries": ["Василий", "Иван"],
  "gendre": "Хорор",
  "content": "Любовь самолет вертолет корабль",
  "ageRestriction": 18,
  "description": "Король кокаина, террорист, один из известнейших и богатейших преступников… Да, речь идёт о Пабло Эскобаре! Кража надгробий, продажа сигарет и подделка лотерейных билетов переросли в угон дорогих авто, рэкет и убийства. Фильм «Эскобар» – история наркобарона, семьянина и политика.1982 год. Наркобарон Пабло Эскобар знакомится с Вирхинией Валехо – известной журналисткой. Девушка становится его биографом и любовницей. Из мемуаров женщины мы узнаём о жизни и стремлениях Эскобара: он появляется в большой политике и занимает место в Конгрессе Колумбии. Будучи в большой политике, он сохраняет верность своим старым методам, отработанным в преступном мире: угрозы, насилие и шантаж. Но с началом антикокаиновой кампании его карьера в этой сфере заканчивается.После громкого скандала со взрывом Бионга над Баготой и волны политического террора карьера бывшего босса идёт к закату; на Эскобара начинается настоящая охота властей. Спустя пару лет он всё же сдаётся и переезжает в специальную тюрьму… Где для него организованы коттедж, сады, джакузи и рабочее место – ведь он продолжает управлять своим бизнесом. Впрочем, Пабло сбежал и оттуда. Смотри фильм «Эскобар» и узнай обо всех перипетиях судьбы одного из самых знаменитых в мире криминальных авторитетов!Кинокартина, снятая при участии Болгарии, Испании и США, основана на мемуарах Вирхинии Вальехо – той самой журналистки, по сюжету ставшей биографом Эскобара. Цепляет не только сюжет, но и звёздный актёрский состав: Хавьер Бардем и Пенелопа Крус, Питер Сарсгаард и Жульет Рестрепо. Впрочем, каждому из них пришлось потратить немало сил на то, чтобы вжиться в роль: Хавьер Бардем, к примеру, сильно набрал вес для роли, а Пенелопа Крус посмотрела десятки видео со своей героиней и призналась, что это была одна из сложнейших ролей в её карьере.",
  "actors": ["Василий", "Иван"],
  "url": "/films/Airbuss/1.mp4"
}
```

Не понимаю в чем проблема ибо я передаю список строк как и требует призма